# Cannot send email using Laravel 5

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-5

I wrote this code a couple of months ago. I used to be able to send email with the following configuration. But suddenly today, I am getting the following error.

> Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 265:
>    Connection could not be established with host localhost [Connection timed out #110]

This is the configuration from which I was able to send emails.

```
'driver' => 'smtp',

'host' => 'localhost',

'port' => 587,

'from' => ['address' => "test@xxx.com", 'name' => "test"],

'encryption' => 'tls',

'username' => 'test@xxx.com',

'password' => '*********',

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

'pretend' => false,
```

Comment: Save your mail configurations within `.env` file

Comment: Its hidden file at the root level of your project

Comment: why are you connecting to your localhost on port 587 try connecting it on port 25

Comment: @Uchiha, I am sorry to bother you again but I cannot find the .env file.

Comment: @KhanShahrukh, it was working with port 587 couple of days ago. But now, it is not. I have using port 25. It is still giving me the same error.

Comment: By suddenly you probably mean "after this system update" or "after the latest Laravel update", right? Did you change something?

Comment: @Tim, no, I didnt change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. The configuration is wrong. I dont know why it worked earlier. But now I have followed the instructions from this [link](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/how-do-i-find-out-my-smtp-info.76045/) and now it is working.

Step 1 -> Go to "Email Account". You can find the icon at the home page of the cpanel.

Step 2 -> Click on the account next to the account you want to use. You will see a dropdown menu. There you will see an option saying "Configure Mail Client". Click on it.

Step 3 -> There at the bottom of the page you will find the proper settings. Look for outgoing server settings.